# How to detect the current URL and then forward based on it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox and an image button as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnExecute" runat="server" OnClick="btnExecute_Click" />
```

Now here is my problem, on the Page_Load there are some bindings.. and these bindings go into dozens of controls and classes, by the time it's about to reach my code in the `On_Click` for my button its too late.. it would redirect to somewhere else.. I needed to redirect to a different page but it would never reach its destination unless i somehow ommit all the stuff in between which i am not willing to do..

So, the solution that i thought is to use Javascript on that image button `OnClientClick`, unfortunately I am not so good at it and was hoping you could help me.. the pseudo code would be something like this

```
if(the current url contains some page.aspx)
      {
          var value = get the value from myText;

          then navigate to  myotherpage?txtvalue=value;
      }
```

Can someone help me with this javascript without going into to much details on why i am doing it like this? please

I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naively translating your pseudo code to javascript:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('page.aspx') > -1)
{
    var value = document.getElementById('<%= myText.ClientID %>').value;
    window.location.href = 'myotherpage?txtvalue=' + encodeURIComponent(value);
}
```

Comment: sorry meant to give you the answer but i glanced to quick to and saw your name above hehe

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("page.aspx") != -1) {
    var val = document.getElementById("myText").value;
    window.location = "/myotherpage?txtvalue=" + encodeURIComponent(val);
}
```

Comment: It's up to the OP to use an appropriate ID from the object on the browser page.  They did not show the actual generated HTML so I have no idea what the actual ID is (as I don't know ASP or care to).  I just used "myText" based on their pseudo-code.

Comment: that's the problem with ASP.NET. You never have idea of the actual generated id. That's why you must use server side construct to fetch the actual id as illustrated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you jfriend for the help, i gave you a vote up.. but Darin helped me with the ASP syntax.